# Custom KalDataSource I tried to implement it but I'm getting an error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, calendar

I try using a custom kal datasource for my calendar. I succeeded in getting the data, and when I tried to run it I keep getting this error:

```
-[NSNull cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2823fb8
```

My code

```
//  KalParseDataSource.m

#import "KalParseDataSource.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation KalParseDataSource

static BOOL IsDateBetweenInclusive(NSDate *date, NSDate *begin, NSDate *end)
{
    return [date compare:begin] != NSOrderedAscending && [date compare:end] != NSOrderedDescending;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        events= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource protocol conformance

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Filler text";
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate{
    NSLog(@"getting data");
    if ([events count] > 0) {
        [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
        return;
    }
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CalendarEvents"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [events removeAllObjects];
            [events addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

}

- (NSArray *)markedDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate {
    return [[self tagsFrom:fromDate to:toDate] valueForKeyPath:@"date"];
}

- (void)loadItemsFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate {
    [items addObjectsFromArray:[self tagsFrom:fromDate to:toDate]];
}

- (NSArray *)tagsFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate
{
    NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (PFObject *event in events){
        if (IsDateBetweenInclusive([event objectForKey:@"event_date"], fromDate, toDate)){
            [matches addObject:event];
        }
    }
    return matches;
}

- (void)removeAllItems{
    [items removeAllObjects];
}
@end
```

My view controller holding the calendar.

```
#import "MainMenuViewController.h"
#import "Kal.h"
#import "KalParseDataSource.h"
@interface MainMenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainMenuViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    id<KalDataSource> source = [[KalParseDataSource alloc] init];
    KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    calendar.dataSource = source;


    [self addChildViewController:calendar];
    [calendar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:calendar.view];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

I'm stuck with this for 3 days, Can anyone give  simple example in using this 3rd party framework https://github.com/klazuka/Kal ? The one on the repo seems a bit complicated, I just want to use a custom data source.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the function `cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear` you are calling with `null` just put a debug there from wherever the function is being called and check if the function being called is on `NSDate` and it is not released.

And you can always `Enable Zombies` to find the released object when crash happens. You can track if any variable gets released via setting `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`. With zombies enabled, messages to deallocated objects will no longer behave strangely or crash in difficult-to-understand ways, but will instead log a message and die in a predictable and debugger-breakpointable way. 
You can set `NSZombieEnabled` by the following steps.

Select Product from the menu bar above. Keep alt/option pressed and select "Test..." or "Run...".

1.
Go to the Arguments tab, and add `NSZombieEnabled` `YES` in the "Environment Variables" section.

OR

2.
Go to the Diagnostics tab, and check `Enable Zombie Objects` in the "Memory Management" section.

Comment: Or, better than either of those, run your app under Instruments's Zombies template. That will give you more information than the debugger can.